# Differences between Windows registry and UNIX/Linux approach

Tags: linux, configuration

What are the main differences between the Windows registry and the approach used in UNIX/Linux, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: Hmm, gconf is something similar to registry, used by gnome.

Comment: -1: too many questions, subjective arguments, and inviting discussion.

Comment: @Sardathrion, how is "too many questions" a bad thing? Is it against the site policy?

Comment: @Sardathrion, and how is "inviting discussion" a bad thing? Perhaps the question clashes with community policy as it is phrased, but I am sure it can be objectively answered. As such I will appreciate help in rephrasing it. Apparently genuine curiosity is a bad thing to some people.

Comment: If you have three questions, there should be three questions and not one.  The last question, by stating that Linux/Unix is superior invites bad subjective -- see FAQ. Note that for SE sites, inviting discussion is indeed a bad thing -- see FAQ. I think there are good questions here, but as they stand they are not fitting in the format of the site.  Since this is community driven, I'll let others pile in.

Comment: "What are the main differences between the Windows Registry and the approach used in UNIX/Linux, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real cognate in UNIX, but as wollud1969 says, `/etc` comes close. That, though, is only part of the story. You'd also need to consider things under `/var` (for information about installed software, running services, etc), `/usr/local/etc` (at least on FreeBSD and certain Linux distros) for configuration information for installed third party apps, and of course each user's dotfiles, which customise how software works for them (roughly equivalent the the `HK_CURRENT_USER` hive in the registry). Then there's `/dev` for device interfaces, `/proc` for running process data, and the kernel itself (either through `sysctl`, a `kernfs` virtual file system, etc). Depending on your particular platform, there may be other places to look, too.

The primary advantage in the UNIX approach, from my perspective as a UNIX user these last 12 years, is that application config files, wherever they live, are usually just plain old text files, so can be read and edited by plain old humans. (Except, possibly, the sendmail config file, but that's a completely different religious war...). Many applications (browsers, desktop apps, etc) create config files for you, but they are text files, and the apps usually won't stop working if those files are then edited by hand, provided the edits don't break their syntax. The downside, though, is that there is no universal config language, so you need to learn the syntax for each app you manage. In reality, though, this is only a small annoyance at worst.

The Windows Registry was developed, at least in part, to address a similar state of affairs that was deemed problematic by Microsoft, where application ini files were not centrally managed, with no strict control on what values went in them, and no standard location for software to put them. The registry fixes some of those concerns (it is centrally managed, with specific data types that can be stored in it), but its disadvantages are its binary format, so that even experienced Windows admins need to use a GUI tool to look at it, it's prone to getting corrupted if you lose power, and not all software authors are sufficiently conscientious to clean up after themselves when you decide to uninstall their kewl shareware app. And, as with almost any other file in Windows, it's entirely possible for the various components of the registry to become fragmented on disk, resulting in painfully slow read and update operations. There is no requirement for software to make use of the registry, and even Microsoft's own .NET platform uses XML files instead.

The Wikipedia page about the [registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) is quite informative.

Answer (score 8):

It is certainly not directly comparable, but I would think of the /etc directory as the counterpart of the Windows registry.

One major advantage, at least from my point of view, of the /etc directory is: you can open each and any file with your favorite text-editor and read, hopefully understand and modify or fix it.

The Windows registry is stored in some specific binary format and you read/write it with the registry editor, which does not simply show you what's in the file but which interprets it for you. Furthermore, everything is in one big file.

Comment: There is no requirement for any application on linux/unix to store its configuration in any particular way, nor is there any dependency on that configuration from other applications, normally. This is not true of course for cases where one application explicitly depends on others. Having said this, I think there is a lot of flexibility that comes with this model. Transparency has been mentioned of course, but I think the flexibility is critical today where systems could be built in many different ways and apps could be on local disk, NFS, etc. File structure freedom is important.

Comment: I'd like to know why they are "not directly comparable" (both seem like configuration for applications), while /etc/ is (these unix directories are cryptic despite being English dictionary words).

Answer (score 5):

Why it is criticized so much? For me it's just for one point: transparency. The registry doesn't has any, imo. 
Objectively:

- it is error prone when tweaking around
- can get fragmented
- crap entries are often not deleted when deinstalling software
- too many key types (DWORD, QWORD, string, binary, unicorns etc.)